# Drush status runs the correct PHP version, drush sql-dump don't

Tags: drush

I set the drush alias in my .bash_profile as stated in the doc:

```
alias drush='DRUSH_PHP=/usr/local/php54/bin/php /home/dx_/drush/drush'
```

when I run the "drush status" the correct php version shows up

```
PHP configuration     :  /usr/lib/php5.5/php.ini
```

But when I want to run a drush sql-dump

```
The external command could not be executed due to an application error.                                                [error]
                                 [error]ly (returned: X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
```

I tried to add an alias in aliases.drushrc.php but with no success.

Anyone sees what could be the problem?

Comment: Show the complete output of your sql-dump command, with the --debug flag set. From the partial information shown above, my guess is that you are running `drush status` locally to confirm the version of the local PHP, but you are probably using some remote alias (`drush @remote sql-dump`), and running into a problem with the PHP version on the remote machine. Please also show the complete contents of any alias you are using (with any sensitive information redacted).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks greg for taking time to answer me.

Sorry I was just stupidly running my drush command at the root of my server and not in my website directory and the error message was stated "X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9" which made me confuse

```
(uiserver):uxxxxxxx:~ > drush sql-dump
The external command could not be executed due to an application     [error]
error.
The command could not be executed successfully (returned:            [error]
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in
<b>/homepages/xx/dxxxxxxxxxxx/htdocs/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/environment.inc</b>
on line <b>545</b><br />
, code: 255)
```

How ever the only .bash_profile setting that works for me is as follow:

```
alias drush='/usr/bin/php5.5-cli ~/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php'
export COLUMNS
```

As you said yourself in one of your post aliasing drush to call php directly is **outdated**. But I couldn't successffully set the DRUSH_PHP variable.

this

```
alias drush="~/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php"
export DRUSH_PHP='/usr/bin/php5.5-cli'
export PATH="$DRUSH_PHP:$PATH"
export COLUMNS
```

or this

```
alias drush='DRUSH_PHP=/usr/local/php54/bin/php ~/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php'
export COLUMNS
```

both give me:

```
(uiserver):uxxxxxxxx:~ > drush status
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in <b>/homepages/xx/dxxxxxxxxx/htdocs/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/environment.inc</b> on line <b>545</b><br />
```

Am I doing something wrong?